# Execute raw SQL using Doctrine 2 with Doctrine paginator

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do the pagination, but there is an error:

```
$dql = "SELECT cast(ip as CHAR) as ip FROM histories";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql)->setFirstResult($offset)->setMaxResults($limit); 
$paginator = new Paginator($query);  
$maxpage = ceil($paginator->count() / $limit);
```

Error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable |
>   ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
>   PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got '*'
>
> $maxpage = ceil($paginator->count() / $limit); //error line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try that :

```
$maxpage = ceil(count($paginator) / $limit);
```

[Read the doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html)